# Is it an emoji?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, unicode

I've been working on this iOS app recently and I encountered a (rather easily solved) problem: How do I determine if my string is comprised only of emojis?

Well, that's your job today!

#### Input

A string. If the presence of unicode characters is problematic for you then you may use a different reasonable format. Please state what you do if you do something different from a regular string for taking input.

#### Output

Print or return a truthy value if the input string contains only emojis, and a falsey value if it contains any characters other than emojis.

#### Wait a sec... what's an emoji?

An emoji is a character that falls in these ranges:

```
0x1F600...0x1F64F  // Emoticons
0x1F300...0x1F5FF  // Misc Symbols and Pictographs
0x1F680...0x1F6FF  // Transport and Map
0x2600...0x26FF    // Misc symbols
0x2700...0x27BF    // Dingbats
0xFE00...0xFE0F    // Variation Selectors
```

(I think)

#### This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins❕

#### Test cases

```
"Is it an emoji? " -> False
"code-golf" -> False
"    " -> False
"I have no fancy emojis :(" -> False

"" -> True
"" -> True
```

For you poor souls who cannot see emojis, [here is an image of the test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Ji5.png).

Comment: Perhaps include a version (maybe an image) for those who can't see emojis? ;-)

Comment: @ETHproductions, do you suggest I link to a photo of the test cases or something else?

Comment: Well, there are emojis spread throughout the whole question, but I guess the only really important ones are in the test cases, so an image of just the test cases will work.

Comment: @ETHproductions, I added a link to a photo of the test cases

Comment: Can input be a numeric array of Unicode code points? Also, what range of characters/numbers can the input contain?

Comment: @LuisMendo, I suppose you can take an array of Unicode code points. The range of characters is the range I have above in the question in addition to any printable ASCII character.

Comment: I'm going to vote to re-open. I don't see a valid reason as to why this is unclear. If a string contains only emojis, it's a truthy. if not, it's a falsy.

Comment: You forgot some emoji: [vomiting emoji](https://xkcd.com/1813/), [combining bloodstain](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=36371992#36371992)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>61</s> 56+1 = <s>62</s> <s>57</s> 47 bytes

Uses the `-n` flag and takes input from STDIN. Prints `0` for truthy and `nil` for falsy.

-5 bytes because for some reason I initially thought the regex solution would not work???

-10 bytes from [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob) for noticing a code point overlap that I missed :o

```ruby
p$_=~/^[--☀-➿︀-︀️]*$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0Al3rZOPy76w/yeBt0P82f2f5g/C8SYvf/RjAbdR/P2v9/RoAvE73f0x2qp6P///2H@jC4gnvEvv6AkMz@v@L9uHgA)

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0Al3rZOPy76w/yeBt0P82f2f5g/C8SYvf/RjAbdR/P2v9/RoAvE73f0x2qp6P///2H@jC4gnvEvv6AkMz@v@L9uHgA) if you merge two ranges in the regex.

Comment: That's 47 isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to update the score after getting the suggestion from @NieDzejkob

Answer (score 13):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 179 bytes

```
a➡na◀n 9728▶n 10175◀n 65024▶n 65039◀n 127744▶n 128591◀n 128640▶n 12876701
```

A callable that takes a list of integers representing the codepoints and returns 1 or 0.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFdToQwEMff9xQ9AkWgcAAPQlgSMRHMwgFWXjYQF9fY6AYTG5LNxhdf1cTbcILeAGfasrDGhw7z2fn/aHyTXSdRtowHKR7upNhuFgTskST5JZYGTIVg3qXYtVK0Zf/W4UcKXqaQ77C4gVNL0VR4@pd1SgJm@xDU/fNnSqhFmavSnmvZzth4qkP2IlB1ajPmONOg7bsBNRXfc6wxyzxm1jYWmMqchqIzaAKkus2StMgh5l9kDgHB7tuQFnFeLMMixK6DvpV3ivLxHikR0iw7avKJFZX@8etRGMw3c20Qb7XPD7ialyS6CldhVMQrVNLNleA7oMifc4x2NqPkV8rWYPavhKL/MT7d@aS5cL82mKhF61Dqnv7paKaOhfqvvw)

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 187 bytes

```
a➡iani◀n 9728▶n 10175◀n 65024▶n 65039◀n 127744▶n 128591◀n 128640▶n 128767
```

A callable that takes a string and returns a boolean.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f9hfn/jh/m97VwKQHKZQmaxK0jqP0go8cP8KQsfzVv4Yf7EHiCzKRMouDARJANSmvdh/iywUNeH@X2dIPxoekOegqW5kQWQ0/Vo2rY8BUMDQ3NTsLCZqYGRCUwhXB4oamwJljc0Mjc3MUFoNLIwtTSEyliYmRjARM3NzKEO6AM6C4h7O6EYxO8Fsf8rQBzVuxbqGaDbl0A0oXgH5BuYZ0B@QfYKyCFo7C5C9sKs4VIAOmBGA4QLkpqyBBy4IMWTMRX0IRRwgZ0PAA)

### Ungolfed and explained

```
 A callable that takes a  called input and returns a 
 input  ➡ 
  For each character in input
  character  input 
   Create a frozen called n containing the unicode codepoint of character
   n  character
   If the value is in one of specific ranges, return  (if the current character is not an emoji)
  ◀n 9728▶n 10175◀n 65024▶n 65039◀n 127744▶n 128591◀n 128640▶n 128767
    
  
 
  Since we're here, all characters are an emoji, so return
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLNTgIxEL7zFHNTEw6AwMLRGE08@wS1DFDFlnS7mnhCLkYia4xEjQcJCeHmzfhAPAFvgDPt8hM8tNud7@s3880Ur82lkqaBy8X4@X4xHj7kgPYZqPiEIQq//MARSNHpiIsOgmsLB05cYQyCmKOJh7ABSncTB0I3wKJLrA74y1OORTPU8@dfkwCA1z41FlDINsi2sEI6tEQOfGaM@lsASU3WUlxqkDi2KBxSvqY1d6hXFdHBaCeUVrpFdSMk2lsF3rpGaQemuVH3auRc0@ezvxOnLGdNL3IjOglSe7hKo5El4i5K1VQSrNAtjPNZB/haCvsq3JOJtUgpt2zGoA23DJBbfRAKGCzG6SOv@XtPQz0q1ehnMH/71VAsFKOKD1crhVJ5RVzjFD2se7xYiqJyeXOxVKvUixlSq5YLq2hUjbJGcurUVxzKeMytd/J@rrREuMU9i9BGi3mgFm@s0KwJWBnJQ2y2WjD0Sqk/seQyczn8zt4YDXnKVfDroMfBb4PnzsMO4eGMJ7LdG3a2cx5kXE6Ucp5s@cThHNJ4fx@98MvQaBq80nr9T0g3hFD@Hw)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 39 bytes

Since [the proposal for Unicode property escapes](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes) is now part of V8, this can also be addressed without manually specifying ranges. Granted, this comes years after the original question was asked, but I think it is an interesting addition none the less.

```javascript
a=>/^\p{Emoji_Presentation}*$/u.test(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU4xbsJAEOz9ipEVCRvZ0EaxgCoFHT0h6OTckUPm1vItlhDKByhSUbijIVJCQZ9f8QPHhwnFjnZmdlazFKWwaaFzjsvHOiVjGQoD1GIw7L@@5NvnFS31fFJIKw0L1mQ@ug/9dY@l5UCEdeK1IW3yNdsmOfUAf2yhGcJAuvgIl8Nx70fOuRz2vym9yXhBmXLkX67OzVX15eDbwY@DU@uO8S5KCUNQwqSb9qvFU3APf963XTOV780ST1GB4NaO5Qqkbi1DOJUy2ctoETgvQicediKoKwvDpP4D)

Comment: Amazing, TIL about Unicode property escapes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 87 bytes

```python
lambda x:re.match('^[---☀-➿︀-︀️]*$',x)and 1
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqihVLzexJDlDQz0u@sP8GQ26H@bP7P8wvwfEmL7/w/xZIMbs/Y@AMo/m7X@/o0EXiN/v6I/VUlHXqdBMzEtRMOTKzC3ILypRKEr9n6hgqxDNpaCg5FmskFmikJinkJqbn5Vpr/Bh/pIpSjogmQ/zp@xMzk9J1U3Pz0kDcWDCM9YBVc1YCiJWgIiVIGIVRNZTISOxLFUhL18hLTEvuRJiarGClQZccx@c1QXEM5S4Yrm4uNLyixSyFTLzFBKtuDgLijLzSjTUq61sTAxqFapr1fWA0kDPa2TrKKRpZGtqav4HAA)

Returns `1` as truthy value and `None` as falsy value.

Comment: I "borrowed" your regex, hope you don't mind ;)

Comment: Since I told Value Ink about it, I'll tell you too - the first two groups in the regex can be merged because of adjacent codepoints: `-`

Comment: -12 bytes by using a better regex and using re.sub instead of re.match [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY6xTsMwEIZ3P8XJSxPJYWGLZJj7DKWD29rUqLEj@0DtlhkhunQIIOEFJGBgLlPfpS9Qv0GIqejwf/rv/rvT1SucW3PeKX7VLUQ1mQlYlk6e@dtJNhjF8NAUMTytY3hO5mW3b5ti/7o7bJui12G7Hg8YpWyZc04p0VVtHYKTHUqPHjiMCAAdetAIwoCs7I2@hBjeNpSlJIbNz9TOZHFtFyoV/@32u59q3xM@Ej4Tvo7pEObiToKxoISZro5XPZTZafnx5O57tZSMCSHKOkDQBv5@KwnUThvMkFF@QRmoDPO8@wU "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 54 bytes

```
map(/[--☀-➿︀-︀️]/.match)+all
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z83sUBDP/rD/J4G3Q/zZ/Z/mD8LxJi9/9GMBt1H8/a/39GgC8Tvd/TH6uvlJpYkZ2hqJ@bk/C8oyswr0UjTUP8wf8Y6IF4KxCuAeCUQr1LX1PwPAA)

-9 bytes (3 chars) thanks to NieDzejkob

"Borrowing" Uriel's regex :P This is shorter thanks to Proton's obscure features and regex literals

Comment: As I told Value Ink, the first two groups in the regex can be merged because of adjacent codepoints: `-`

Comment: @NieDzejkob How exactly? It gives me errors: https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z83sUBDP/rD/BkNuh/mT9//Yf4sEGP2/kdAgUfz9r/f0aALxO939Mfq6@UmliRnaGon5uT8LyjKzCvRSNNQB@pcB8RLgXgFEK8E4lXqmpr/AQ

Comment: like [this](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@59m@z83sUBDP/rD/J4G3Q/zZ/Z/mD8LxJi9/9GMBt1H8/a/39GgC8Tvd/TH6uvlJpYkZ2hqJ@bk/C8oyswr0UjTUP8wf8Y6IF4KxCuAeCUQr1LX1PwPAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 47 bytes

```apl
''≡⍵
[--☀-➿︀-︀️]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/19d/VHnwke9W7miP8zvadD9MH9m/4f5s0CM2fsfzWjQfTRv//sdDbpA/H5HfyzX//8f5s/oAuIZAA)

Is…

`''≡⍵` an empty string identical to the result when…

`[--☀-➿︀-︀️]` all emojis are…

replaced with nothing

?

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>83</s> 61 bytes

-22 bytes thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

`s=>(s.match(/\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g)||"").length==s.length/2`

**Demo**

```js
f=s=>(s.match(/\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g)||"").length==s.length/2

document.writeln(f("code-golf")) //false
document.writeln(f("    ")) //false
document.writeln(f("I have no fancy emojis :(")) //false
document.writeln(f("")) //true
document.writeln(f("")) //true
```

Comment: 61 bytes: `s=>(s.match(/\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g)||"").length==s.length/2`

Comment: Uh, how does this work? The regex doesn't specify the codepoints of any emoji...

Comment: @NieDzejkob I believe JS uses UTF-16 for Unicode, so I guess these are the UTF-16 byte representations of those codepoints. The answer is incomplete though, it fails for ``, `♔☺☠`, `` etc., all of which should be truthy. It seems to check only for one range out of the six that OP mentions.